# C# VS2020 .Net 4.8 Winform application run without .exe.config file

Tags: c#, config

I made C# application usually with .Net 4.7 with VS2020.
Now, I change this to .Net 4.8 and all .exe and .dll files get .config files.

With .Net 4.7, this config files does not need to run application. I just copy .exe and .dll files to folder, then it works.
Now this new application with .Net 4.8 and Net Core 6, I can't run application without these .config files.

Ok, NetCore 6 is another story, just for .Net 4.8, how can I get rid of this .config files for deploy my application for client?
I don't use any installer, this application is for just inner use, simply copy all files to folder and go.

I just check what this .config files contains -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Buffers" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

this is for my application exe file, and next one is for dll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

That's it. Any solution? I can't find similar question and solutions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not reproducible, obviously. I did a test, compiled a simple winforms app against .net framework 4.8, copied the sole executable to a folder and it runs smoothly. Either narrow down your issue to these assembly bindings or at least make a longer explanation of what *I can't run* means in your case.

Comment: I think you mixed up .NET Framwork (v4.8) and .NET (e.g. 6) in your question, this is a bit confusing, [they are not the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)

Comment: If you copy a set of files anyway, why do you care about copying an extra file?

Comment: Julian, maybe your explanation has some hint for me. Indeed, my application uses 3 dlls which I made from .Net 4.7.2, and main application is .Net 4.8. If this is the case, I will recompile all dll with same Net 4.8, and there is no Net6...

Comment: Hello PMF, because it is not tidy on the folder... just I want dll and exe, not other files. Simple answer...

Comment: Wiktor, as Juian said, maybe it is because I mix different .Net versions. I will check about it....

Comment: Even if I use different .Net version dlls and main, is there any way to get rid of this .config files? I can't find any explanation from anywhere about it... weird...

Comment: There's no .NET 4.8, only .NET Framework 4.8. And doesn't require the `exe.config` to exist. .NET 5+ are .NET *Core* 5+. The `Core` part was removed for marketing reasons

Comment: The reason you may need this particular `.config` is because your application mixes versions of the `System.Buffers` and `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` assemblies. The redirects are needed to tell your application which version to load if an old one is requested

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis, I understand. Indeed there is System,Buffers.dll and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll exist on my project, it is automatically included when I build my application. I use NpgSql for SQL connection and MetroFramework for UI. I think those dependencies get mixed up. I will check about it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use `Costura.Fody` which is a simplified abstraction over `ILMerge` to embed everything into a single `.exe` file.

You can read over the documentation for `Costura.Fody` [here.](https://github.com/Fody/Costura)

But installation is rather simple:

```
Install-Package Fody
Install-Package Costura.Fody
```

Create a `FodyWeavers.xml` file in the root of your project:

```
<Weavers>
   <Costura/>
</Weavers>
```

And then simply configure any extra settings like including runtime references, etc. in your `FodyWeavers.xml` file as per the documentation.

Comment: This is interesting, I will see what it can do. Thanks!